# Make the previous X rows, into additional columns [Pandas]

Tags: python, pandas

For example let's say i have one column "a"

I want to give each sample/row the specified amount of "lookback" for previous values.
For example here's what a lookback of 3 should do...

```
  a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5

   a  a1  a2  a3
0  1  Nan Nan Nan
1  2  1   Nan Nan
2  3  2   1   Nan
3  4  3   2   1
4  5  4   3   2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with `f-string`s:

```
n = 3
for c in range(1, n+1):
    df[f'a{c}'] = df['a'].shift(c)
print (df)
   a   a1   a2   a3
0  1  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  2  1.0  NaN  NaN
2  3  2.0  1.0  NaN
3  4  3.0  2.0  1.0
4  5  4.0  3.0  2.0
```

Alternative with list comprehension and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), last add to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
n = 3
r = range(1, n+1)
df = df.join(pd.concat([df['a'].shift(c) for c in r], axis=1, keys=r).add_prefix('a'))
print (df)
   a   a1   a2   a3
0  1  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  2  1.0  NaN  NaN
2  3  2.0  1.0  NaN
3  4  3.0  2.0  1.0
4  5  4.0  3.0  2.0
```